# Tefillin on both arms not simultaneously

Tags: halacha, tefilin

Why do some people wear tefillin on both arms (not simultaneously)?

Comment: Maybe they are ambidextrous? Is this a common thing you saw in some community?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a dispute about whether strength or writing is the deciding factor in determining which hand will be used to wear *tefillin*.
Therefore, some who perform all labor with one hand and write with the other, have the practice toward the end of *davening* to remove the *shel yad* and put it on the opposite arm for a few minutes to be *mekayem* both *shitos*.
For more resources:
https://vaadmhk.org/tefillin-the-right-way/